# Can I have Two scrollhandlers for one scrollpanel?

Tags: gwt, event-handling, scroll, panel

I have a main panel with a scrollpanel.

Embedded in that are two other panels of which only one is shown at a time. I want to catch the scrollevent of the main panel in each of these panels. i have a scrollevent in both the child panels but want just one to be triggered. how do i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many handlers as you like to a ScrollPanel.

So in both panels where you want to listen to the scroll event:

```
HandlerRegistration handler = scrollPanel.addScrollHandler( new ScrollHandler() {
    @Override 
    public void onScroll( ScrollEvent event ) {
       // ... your code
    }
);
```